# When should I Fortify / Consume a hero?

Tags: heroes-of-dragon-age

Quite new to this (level in early 30s / 2 legendary heroes) and just wondering when I should consume a hero vs when should I fortify one.

Here is my guess. Could someone please correct me if I am wrong:

Consume: 
- Anything lower than a rare
- Ideally same color (On this note, if my hero is, say, red/blue does it count them as ALL red and ALL blue for advantages and disadvantages or are any advantages/disadvantages diminished - ie half as good?)
- Even better if they have experience (is it worth getting them experience first or am I better just getting my squad experience)

Fortify:
- Only decent rarity
- Always share a color
- Good if they are "common" eg wisps so you can tier them up
- Experience doesn't matter(?)

Any other tips?

At this point in time I have just removed an experienced (level 15ish) epic from my team and I am wondering if I should fortify a character with him or consume him...

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short:

When consuming,

[If consuming into a Tier 1 unit, it's best to consume Tier 4 units.

If consuming into a Tier 2 unit, it's best to consume Tier 2 units.

If consuming into a Tier 3 unit, it's best to consume Tier 3 units.](http://forums.capitalgames.com/forum/heroes-of-dragon-age/vigil-s-keep-strategy-optimization/70534-post-2-0-tier-up-guide?p=1842142#post1842142)

[The complete chart showing the differences in consuming without bonuses (the base consume point), with faction bonuses, with tier bonuses, and with both bonuses (faction+tier)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pi-_dJRnQwxkIroCg-TB8JXFekL6ovCr7pS2ovGw4Yk/pubhtml#).

You don't have to get experience into your food (consumed toon).

If I had to give you a best practices advice on consuming it would be this:
Always try to consume with same faction and same tier toons when it's available and you aren't in a hurry. Wisps are much better in consuming but you'll get them much rarer.

[Fortifying](http://forums.capitalgames.com/forum/heroes-of-dragon-age/circle-tower-new-players/69418-fortify-the-new-age-of-heroes) is both a much more straightforward process and harder to decide because it's a pure tactical decision. It depends also on many other aspects: your consuming strategy (if you're an f2p or an ptp player), your time investment (how much time do you spend playing the game), your team setup (are you focusing on specific team setups or on all-around team setups) etc.

In general; If you're using toons (not wisps) for fortification then you have to be careful when using higher tier (especially legendary) toons. Fortified slots can't be emptied, so when using legendary toons in slots you have to remember this and if you don't want to waste your hard earned legendary fort (surplus) toons (which are the rarest toons) plan accordingly.

Yes it's better to use legendary wisps in slots but if you want to power up your target toon faster and therefore don't want to wait for hard to find legendary wisps than you should know that finding more than one of a specific legendary fort food to achieve higher than Tier 1 (T1) slots could take a much longer time.

Spreading all your legendary T1 fort food into all of the available slots of the target toon is a good strategy to power up your toon the fastest way. But then you would have to wait a long time before tiering up the slots.

Certain toons would benefit from targeting the fortification of legendary toons into certain slots (power vs shield slots) because of their [abilities and/or auras](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XqZIetKv1s4NxhCPY7N3E53qi6xbXCVx2Ctt-3dAh6s/edit).

Considering all of the above the question of consume-or-fortify becomes a hard one to answer. A general rule of thumb would be to mostly consume (or collect to tier up before consuming) rare (and lower) toons, strategically fortify or consume (or collect to tier up before consuming) surplus epic toons, and definitely collect and/or fortify (or collect to tier up before fortifying) surplus legendary toons but surely there would be exceptions. The question of if you should tier-up legendary surplus toons (and to what degree) before fortifying is another strategic decision.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm taking from this, at my point in the game: 1. Combine 4 similar guys before consuming them at tier 1. 2. Experience does nothing when you fortify. 3. Don't fortify more than one rarity below your character unless desperate (I'm currently fortifying rares). Thanks!